Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int while inserting records into table
I am using a script to automatically update a database daily to sync Azure Blob Storage with a queryable Azure SQL Server database. Among deleting and updating records, I will insert brand new records that meet a certain criteria. The following is an insert statement that I am working with currently.
The first record is inserted into the database without issue, however, the second record throws an error:

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '[{"Date":"2019-06-17"},{"Index":"2"},{"PAN":"987"},{"Phase":"Construction"},{"Primary":"False"},{"Project ID":"3484"}]' to data type int.

The column that this nvarchar is referencing is defnied as a nvarchar(MAX), not an int.
Database schema: https://gyazo.com/b95367d03e71b6f1138111668bf56e05
Create a table...
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [BlobSync].[BlobInventory]
(
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AccountName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CreationTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastModified] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Etag] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ContentLength] [bigint] NULL,
    [ContentType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ContentEncoding] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ContentLanguage] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [BlobType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [AccessTier] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Metadata] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Deleted] [bit] NULL,
    [RemainingRetentionDays] [int] NULL,
    [TagCount] [int] NULL,
    [Tags] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LastUpdatedUTC] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_BlobInventory] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                      OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempTableInsert; 

SELECT * 
INTO #TempTableInsert 
FROM [BlobSync].[BlobInventory] 
WHERE [ID] < 0; 

INSERT INTO #TempTableInsert (AccountName, Name, CreationTime, LastModified, Etag, ContentLength, ContentType, ContentEncoding, ContentLanguage, BlobType, AccessTier, Metadata, Deleted, RemainingRetentionDays, Tags, TagCount, LastUpdatedUTC) 
VALUES 
(
'blobstoragename'
, 'project-images/bdb70f3e-8d8b-41f1-b357-66e1792280e9'
, '7/22/2024 2:28:44 PM'
, '7/23/2024 12:53:18 PM'
, '0x8DCAB597AF04A5D'
, 2380580
, 'image/avif'
, null
, null
, 'BlockBlob'
, 'Cool'
, '{"Description":"This is a description.","FileName":"20190611_120704.jpg"}'
, null
, null
, '[{"Date":"2019-06-17"},{"Index":"1"},{"PAN":"23567"},{"Phase":"Design"},{"Primary":"False"},{"Project ID":"3484"}]'
, 6
, null),
('blobstoragename'
, 'project-images/dd7f2b7e-a824-4ab9-992f-4eae791f8bc6'
, '7/22/2024 2:28:44 PM'
, '7/22/2024 2:28:45 PM'
, '0x8DCAA9DA602D97F'
, 1668161
, 'image/avif'
, null
, null
, 'BlockBlob'
, 'Cool'
, '{"Description":"TEST2","FileName":"20190611_120706.jpg"}'
, null
, null
, '[{"Date":"2019-06-17"},{"Index":"2"},{"PAN":"987"},{"Phase":"Construction"},{"Primary":"False"},{"Project ID":"3484"}]'
, 6
, null); 

INSERT INTO [BlobSync].[BlobInventory] 
    SELECT 
        AccountName, [Name], [CreationTime], [LastModified],
        [Etag], [ContentLength], [ContentType], [ContentEncoding],
        [ContentLanguage], [BlobType], [AccessTier], [Metadata],
        [Deleted], [RemainingRetentionDays], [Tags], [TagCount],
        [LastUpdatedUTC]
    FROM 
        #TempTableInsert 
    WHERE 
        (#TempTableInsert.[AccountName] + '/' + #TempTableInsert.[Name] NOT IN (SELECT [BlobInventory].[AccountName] + '/' + [BlobInventory].[Name] FROM [BlobSync].[BlobInventory])); 

I have used this script before without error and it has worked, for an unknown reason this SQL code will not work in my C# script or when I use it in SSMS (For the second record).

You need to provide an actual [mre] here. We lack to DDL of your table, so we can't reproduce the problem.

Why do you create a temporary table form the table, insert into that temporary table and then insert into the table you replicate d? Just insert straight into the table

Looks like you have tags and tagcount the wrong way round

@ThomA Okay, I added the DDL of my table. I first insert into a temporary table because I need to use a WHERE clause as to not insert duplicate data. Some days I only have to insert 2 records like while others I have to insert 50,000 records. I grab my data from a blob storage inventory, which are a bunch of csv files that lists over 800,000 blobs I am currently storing. My C# script filters out most of that data based on the CreationTime and LastModified fields, which help me to determine if I need to insert or update the record.

The TagCount and Tags fields are reversed between the column list and the column data. So you're putting the value 6 into Tags and the long value [{"Date":"2019-0... into TagCount.

While I'm here, it is not correct to provide datetime values as SQL literals like this: 7/22/2024 2:28:44 PM. Different languages and cultures have their own expectations around how date and times are formatted. The SQL language is no different just because it's a programming language.
The value should be formatted in one of these two ways:

2024-07-22T14:28:44  (ie: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss)
20240722 14:28:44  (ie: yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss)

If you have only the date (no time), the only correct option looks like this:

20240722 (ie: yyyyMMdd - no seperators!)

Anything else is wrong, and leaves you open to potential invalid input or reading the wrong date.

Thank you. The CSV's that I retrieve the data from store the dates as '7/22/2024 2:28:44 PM'. Even though the insert query uses this format, the data gets stored as '2024-07-22 14:28:44.000'. Is this acceptable?

@TristanGoers If you have initial data that's not formatted natively for SQL Server, you should parse and reformat it before the insert, rather than passing it blindly. But also you are mistaken on how the data is stored internally. The table definition shows a datetime column, which means the actual format is binary and not human-readable. Values like 2024-07-22 14:28:44.000 are a convenience provided by your query tool or debugger.
